# Dask read CSV files recursively from directories

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

For the following directory structure

```
Folder
  Sub-Folder1
           File1.csv
           File2.csv
           File3.csv
           File4.csv
  Sub-Folder2
           File1.csv
           File2.csv
  Sub-Folder3
           File1.csv
           File2.csv
```

How can I use `read_csv` of `Dask` to read all the CSV files in these folders, each into one partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

dfs = dd.read_csv('Folder/**/*.csv')
```

Ouput:

```
>>> dfs
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                   A      B      C
npartitions=8                     
               int64  int64  int64
                 ...    ...    ...
...              ...    ...    ...
                 ...    ...    ...
                 ...    ...    ...
Dask Name: read-csv, 8 tasks
```